# How to get the class through reflection and then pass in the generic?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

There is such a function

```kotlin
public inline fun <reified W : ListenableWorker> PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder(
    repeatInterval: Duration
): PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder {
    return PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(W::class.java, repeatInterval)
}
```

requires passing in a generic. How do I set this generic through reflection? The following is the pseudocode.

```kotlin
val work = Class.forName("com.demo.work")
PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<work::class>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
```

Comment: Are you sure `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder` is as you write as the reifying needs an external parameter to work, I think.

Comment: @AndrewL It's not written by me, it's an android class. So I don't know how to set generics.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the generic through reflection, because the function does not exist at runtime. The function is an inline function which gets inlined, i.e. every call of the function is replaced by its body.

For instance, when you write

```
PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<com.demo.Work>(someDuration).build()
```

somewhere in your code, the compiled code will not contain a function call of `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder` inline function (which does not exist in the compiled code), but instead there will be byte code that can be decompiled to

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(com.demo.Work::class.java, someDuration).build()
```

You cannot pass in a generic class via reflection into the inline function, because for the inlining, the compiler has to know the exact type at compile-time.

So, if you want to pass in a generic `Class` parameter, you cannot use the inline function. But that's not at all necessary, because you can just use the code inside the function, i.e.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Class.forName("com.demo.work"), someDuration)
```

This manual inlining of an inline function should work in every possible case, because everything inside an inline function has to be accessable everywhere where you could use the inline function. Otherwise, the inlining of the inline function by the compiler would lead to incorrect code.

Comment: I know this way of passing in generics. But I want to pass in generics by fully qualified class name.

Comment: Yes, then do that and use the fully qualified class name, as in the first code block above.

Comment: I mean ClassName, and in your code is a Class.

Comment: @SageJustus Okay, now I understand what you are trying and extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: What should I do if the third-party library does not provide a builder?

Comment: @SageJustus I rewrote the answer, that should make it clear. TL;DR: The approach does always work.

Comment: ok, I will study hard about this content.